# How to change document.write into a function for ASCII art

Tags: javascript, function

I am fairly new in development so I am going to try my best in phrasing my question accurately. Well, it is pretty simple, I have written a script below which draws a Christmass Tree as ASCII art on the webpage. I have used document.write. I want to however:

- Check if my code can be made simpler
- Convert it into a function and still make it display on to the webpage

I am not very familiar with using the DOM yet and tried console.log but I am sure I am doing something wrong there considering my relatively low experience. Would be great if someone could guide me and show me how this can be made into a solid function which still displays the christmas tree on the browser.

Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
   <p></p>
  <script>
 
//define height and star parameter
 var height=5;
 var star=true;

 //add or remove star

if(star===true){
  for (u=0;u<1;u++) {
  for (r=0;r<height-1;r++) {
    document.write("&nbsp");
  }
  document.write("*</br>");
}
 } else {
  document.write("");
 };

 //create a loop for the pyramid in the tree
for (i=0; i<height; i++) {
  for(r=height-1; r>i; r--) {
    document.write("&nbsp");
  }
   for (k=0; k<=(i*1); k++) { 
    document.write("x");
  }
   document.write("</br>");
 };

 //create trunk of tree
for (u=0;u<1;u++) {
  for (r=0;r<height-1;r++) {
    document.write("&nbsp");
  }
  document.write("I</br>");
}
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at String.prototype.repeat, e.g. `"x".repeat(i)`